# Is there a shortcut to switch between Add and Subtract brushes, in Sculpt mode?

Tags: workflow, sculpting

I'm working on some sculpting but I hate that I have to go to the *Toolshelf* and select `Subtract`, whenever I need that brush. So, while in Sculpt mode, how can I switch between Add and Subtract brush modes, with a shortcut?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to toggle between sculpt modes. While pressed you will be in the opposite mode to what is selected in the toolshelf; i.e. if you have selected *Add*, then while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you will be in *Subtract* Mode.

A list of all [keyboard shortcuts](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Sculpt_Mode#Keyboard_Shortcuts) available in Sculpt Mode.

Comment: Thanks! Crazy that this isn't written anywhere here: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/sculpt_mode.html - or here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_HotKeys/3D_View/Sculpt_Mode

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found this: in the [opened-up] User Preferences » Input » 3D View » Sculpt » "+ Add New"... put "wm.context_menu_enum" in the first box; ignore the (auto-filled) "RNA" box; and put "tool_settings.sculpt.brush.direction" in the "Context Attributes" box. Now assign your carefully chosen shortcut and try it out... You should get a mini menu right under your cursor that offers a *stable* toggle; remote controls the Toolbox switch; & gives on-screen confirmaton (with brush icon color change) *before* you start sculpting. Nice!

I can't find a way to toggle without the menu though: the necessary basic commands "wm.context_cycle_enum" & "wm.context_toggle" both fail in my Blender 2.78a. If the menu irritates you, a way to zip past it is to disable shortcuts for the number keys 1 & 2 (usually sculpt brush select by index & general layer selection) & re-assign both to the Sculpt Add / Subtract shortcut... A quick double press on 1 or 2 then invokes the menu & the numeric position of the required item (Add or Subtract respectively).

Does this mean I get today's Blender nerd prize? :-)

Comment: Using "wm.context_cycle_enum" allows me to instantly switch between one or the other, but it will only switch in one direction. So pressing button 1 will only make it negative, pressing button 2 will only make it positive. It works but dont really understand why it does that instead of cycling through with one button press but it's still better than the menu. 
Is there a way to do this the way I described ?