# Where is Add / Subtract button on sculpting in Blender 2.8

Tags: sculpting

Sorry for the silly question but I'm having trouble finding those button on Blender 2.8. If anyone knows this, could you post screenshot of it or tell me where it is..?

P.s: I'm editing this since this has been identified as possible duplicated of another question. I'm not looking for `ctrl` button to change add and subtract. I wanted to know where the add / subtract button has been moved in Blender 2.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a shortcut to switch between Add and Subtract brushes, in Sculpt mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15113/is-there-a-shortcut-to-switch-between-add-and-subtract-brushes-in-sculpt-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the right in the Tool preferences, you can find them there.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering where it is.